# Having difficulty with new Sitecore installation - can't save edits in Experience Editor (Sitecore 9)

Tags: experience-editor

I've set up a new Sitecore 9 instance on an AWS EC2 instance and I'm having difficulty with some functions while editing.

In the simplest case, I can't save any edited content in Experience Editor - but only when editing external to the EC2 server and only within the Experience Editor (Content Editor allows basic editing without issue).

I access the site externally via Cloudflare HTTPs via a DNS entry routed to an Elastic IP address and have a simple IIS binding of: 
Type: http 
IP address: All Unassigned 
Port: 80
Host name: *

When I navigate to Experience Editor for editing, my basic editing appears to work (I can edit some rich text fields). However, when I hit save, nothing happens. The following appears in my browser console:

```
require.js:121 GET https://<sitename>/sitecore/shell/-/speak/v1/pipelines/pipeline.js?id=%7b73D2BB02-F53F-4045-8BC6-4E3430C291F0%7d&b=1 net::ERR_ABORTED
req.load @ require.js:121
load @ require.js:113
load @ require.js:56
fetch @ require.js:56
check @ require.js:57
enable @ require.js:74
enable @ require.js:102
(anonymous) @ require.js:74
(anonymous) @ require.js:12
each @ require.js:4
enable @ require.js:72
init @ require.js:55
(anonymous) @ require.js:98
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ require.js:118
localRequire @ require.js:98
requirejs @ require.js:118
loadAndInitPipeline @ Pipeline.js:2
initPipeline @ ExperienceEditor.js:89
initAndExecutePipeline @ ExperienceEditor.js:89
execute @ 8313935261293240954.JS:4
runCommandExecute @ ExperienceEditor.js:100
executeCommandFromButton @ ExperienceEditor.js:105
(anonymous) @ RibbonPageCode.js:25
execFunction @ 3727220966836492394.js:912
top.initModalDialog @ 3727220966836492394.js:914
(anonymous) @ RibbonPageCode.js:25
triggerEvents @ backbone.1.0.0.js:10
trigger @ backbone.1.0.0.js:5
execute @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:132
(anonymous) @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:126
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.1.4.4.js:4
execute @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:125
execute @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:112
click @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:81
model.viewModel.(anonymous function) @ sitecore-1.0.2.js:35
(anonymous) @ knockout-2.2.1.js:257
dispatch @ jquery-2.1.1.js:257
elemData.handle @ jquery-2.1.1.js:232
require.js:17 Uncaught Error: Script error for: /sitecore/shell/-/speak/v1/pipelines/pipeline.js?id=%7b73D2BB02-F53F-4045-8BC6-4E3430C291F0%7d&b=1
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:113)
```

This problem is not occurring when I access the site locally, with the main difference being that I'm not going through Cloudflare with HTTPS.

This is probably something fairly fundamental and simple that I'm missing in setting up the site and fixing this may well fix some other editing issues I've found. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are you using the CDN features of Cloudflare? If it is doing _any_ kind of caching, that is going to cause issues for experience editor.

Comment: Thanks Richard - although I don't personally have access to all the Cloudflare settings, I discussed this with a colleague and it's likely that our Cloudflare setup is not going to work well with authoring - as the setup is mainly for the Content Delivery servers of one of our other sites. Once I removed Cloudflare from the equation, all functions that were not working previously were working fine.

If you want to put your comment in answer form, I'll accept that and we can close this off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudflare acts as a CDN, edge caching requests. This will break most editing functions as they require a valid logged in session on the origin server. It is usually best practice for content authors to hit the server directly and not through a caching server.